# Java Regex Html

Tags: java, regex

Trying to get the result of an html:

```
private static final String PATTERN = "(ReportSession=)[0-9A-Za-z]{24}";`

...    

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(".axd?ReportSession=frytm055l51aigbigh5xzrin\u");
if(matcher.find()){
    textView1.setText(matcher.group(1));
}
```

The output is `ReportSession=` but I need to get the whole `ReportSession=frytm055l51aigbigh5xzrin` before the backslash. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `matcher.group(0)` instead of `matcher.group(1)`

Answer (score 3):

You denote groups with parentheses. You have only one inner group, that being (ReportSession=). If you need the whole pattern you can use:

```
matcher.group();
```

or

```
matcher.group(0);
```

Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression m.group(0) is equivalent to m.group(). 
Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29